# Maintaining ArcSDE for PostgreSQL database?

Tags: arcgis-server, postgresql, enterprise-geodatabase, maintenance

I'm getting familiarized with using PostgreSQL for ArcGIS. I've only ever used SQL Server.

I was successful in setting up an ArcSDE database within PostgreSQL 9.2, but what maintenance should I do for PostgreSQL database?

Comment: Lots of Tips (Vacuum pgadmin arcgis tools/scripts) to maintain postgres/postgis http://proceedings.esri.com/library/userconf/proc13/tech-workshops/tw_192.pdf

Comment: unless you have a complex setup, setting autovacuum=on may be all you need (it is enabled by default). Many so called maintenance scripts actually are bad for performance.

Comment: Yeah, I won't get too carried away, I just want to be familiar with them. Does PostGres have a maintenance plan wizard or something similar to SQL Server for daily backups?

Comment: @GISer pgadmin III has these options to do data pumps and backups/maintenance - it should be installed with (as default) postgres

Answer (score 3, accepted):

♦Mapperz:

> Lots of Tips (Vacuum pgadmin arcgis tools/scripts) to maintain
>   postgres/postgis
>   http://proceedings.esri.com/library/userconf/proc13/tech-workshops/tw_192.pdf
>
> pgadmin III has these options to do data pumps and backups/maintenance
>   - it should be installed with (as default) postgres

johanvdw:

> unless you have a complex setup, setting autovacuum=on may be all you
>   need (it is enabled by default). Many so called maintenance scripts
>   actually are bad for performance.